# ILogger to Application Insights

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, logging, azure-application-insights

Using `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore v2.6.1` with .net core v2.2.2 I can see the telemetry going in Azure Application Insight Live Metric Stream but I don't see the entries which I'm trying to log with the `ILogger` inside the `Startup.cs` or in a controller.

I've tried `.UseApplicationInsights()` with `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder` in `Program.cs` and also in `Startup.cs` like so, but to no avail.

```
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry( options => {
  options.EnableDebugLogger = true;
});
```

I see incoming requests and request failure rate but no log entries with

```
this.logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, $"Test Error {Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}");
this.logger.LogTrace($"Test Trace {Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}");
this.logger.LogInformation($"Test Information {Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}");
this.logger.LogWarning($"Test Warning {Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}");
this.logger.LogCritical($"Test Critical {Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}");
this.logger.LogError($"Test Error{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}");
this.logger.LogDebug($"Test Debug {Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}");
```

Answer (score 26):

**update**:

If you have the latest package `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights` (2.9.1) installed, you can follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger#aspnet-core-application).

In program.cs:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .ConfigureLogging(logging=> {
                logging.AddApplicationInsights("your_insturmentation_key");
                logging.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("", LogLevel.Trace); #you can set the logLevel here
            });        
 }
```

Then in the controller.cs:

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        ILogger<HomeController> Logger { get; set; }
        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            this.Logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            Logger.LogTrace("0225 ILogger: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
            Logger.LogDebug("0225 ILogger: debug from index page aa111");
            Logger.LogInformation("0225 ILogger: infor from index page aa111");
            Logger.LogWarning("0225 ILogger: warning from index page aa111");
            Logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, "0225 ILogger: error from index page aa111");
            return View();
        }

        # other code

     }
```

The test result(all logs are sent to application insights):

[image]

Comment: Do you know if there is a way for LogError to map to an Exception on AppInsights? edit: found my answer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger#what-application-insights-telemetry-type-is-produced-from-ilogger-logs-or-where-can-i-see-ilogger-logs-in-application-insights): if you log with an exception object, it maps to an exception telemetry in app insights.

Comment: @ivan-yang is `TelemetryClient client = new TelemetryClient();` necessary?

Comment: @urig, can you let me know which kind of web project are you using? .net core 2.2 or others?

Comment: @urig `TelemetryClient client = new TelemetryClient();` is not necessary. In fact, it is not recommended to create new `TelemetryClient` instances in ASP.NET Core applications. Use constructor injection.

Comment: Do you have to specify the instrumentation key where you did for this to work? I have it set in Configuration, and Program.cs just has `AddApplicationInsights();`, and `TelemetryClient` works (using DI), but `ILogger` isn't sending anything though.

Comment: Ignore me, for some reason I had `ClearProviders()` call on my log buider call chain...

Comment: It should be noted that as per this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/2804 by default they only log `Warning` or above now. This is configurable as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core?tabs=netcorenew%2Cnetcore6#how-do-i-customize-ilogger-logs-collection but results in a lot of noise.